# How to use Javascript/jquery code inside a yii controller action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I want to call a javascript function inside APIController in my yii projects over a repeated interval.

```
 public function actionMytimer() {
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
    $hello = setInterval(test,1000);
    function test(){
        echo 'hellooo interval';
    }  
}
```

Its very necessary for me to run the "test" method in a particular time interval.Is it possible?if not then any way to do this?. Please help.Thanks in advnc.
Here is the current warning message :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function setInterval() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/MediaPult/protected/controllers/APIController.php on line 449
```

Comment: You need to output the entire JavaScript code. You cannot run it in your PHP controller. Try getting it to work in a pure HTML page or jsfiddle.net first and then output the code from you application. [There are examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796021/how-to-use-jquery-with-the-yii-framework)

Comment: If you want to run some method in controller, you need to use [Yii console commands](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could explain the problem more clearly, It'll be easier for people to provide a good solution.

From what I understand, you want to be able to execute a method on the server side repeatedly. For that, you should output the JavaScript code that does this. It'll be something like this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $.get(<?= Yii::app()->request->baseUrl ?>/actionName");
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: You got it right. i want to be able to execute a method on the server side repeatedly.But can i call this from within a controller action? not from a view.

Comment: JavaScript resides on the client side (browser). PHP is on the server side. So to execute JavaScript code, you need to imagine the interaction that'll take place.
To simply test this, you can do an echo "<script>....</script>" from the action. The output of the echo will then be sent to the client. You can check the contents sent to the client by going to the "view source". The JavaScript code will then start execution on the client side sending requests to your action.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute javascript functions from php code just like that. You could try something like:

```
function actionTest(){
  $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
  $cs->registerScript('my_script', 'setInterval(test,1000);', CClientScript::POS_READY);
  $this->render('any_view');
}
```

Comment: am getting trouble in  `$this->render('any_view');` .i dont know how to pass a view name.Becuase i want to run this from a action.